# Make python work with month 13

Tags: python, date

I was using the following code to format date in python 2.7:

```
month = 13 # this is right, i'm working with 13 month.
year = 2012

return datetime.strptime('{}/{}'.format(m, y), '%m/%Y').strftime('%m/%Y')
```

Now i changed to python 2.5, and the code needs changes because .format doesn't exist in this particular version. So, i'm trying like this:

```
 return (datetime.strptime(('%d/%d' % (month, year)),
                            '%m/%Y')
 )
```

And is returning:

```
ValueError: time data did not match format:  data=13/2012  fmt=%m/%Y
```

Which is ok, because i'm using the month = '13', which i really need to use... is it possible to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: obviously not with `datetime.strptime` but you can write your own function that mimics the `datetime.strptime` and does not have the _absurd_ 12 month limitation. It doesn't have to be earth-years after all

Answer (score 0):

How about this,

```
month = 13 
year = 2012

dt = datetime.datetime(year+month//12, month%12, 1)

print(dt)
# 2013-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Nop, i need the 13 month :/

Answer (score 0):

AS You mentioned above you have to use:

```
return (datetime.strptime(('%d/%d' % (month, year)), '%m/%Y'))
```

You having small mistake you are using **'%m/%Y'** here  **month = 13 # this is right, i'm working with 13 month.** There are only 12 months you have to pass range between[1-12].

so you get following error :

ValueError: time data did not match format:  data=13/2012  fmt=%m/%Y